# SVG Logo with Bootstrap

Tags: svg, bootstrap-4

I am developing a web in Bootstrap 4 and in the header I have a SVG format logo that has to be responsive (without fixed size) but it is not possible to visualize it unless you leave the property wide at a fixed value in .px some way to be responsive without leaving a fixed value in .px? Because in Chrome, Opera, Safari, Internet explorer leaving the Width property in auto. In all browsers it appears without problem but in Firefox it does not

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
  <div style="height: 80px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <a href="index">
      <img style="width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;" src="img/imprentaonline24.svg" alt="imprentaonline24" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just remove the `style` from img tag. For responsive svg put the height width inside svg tag

Comment: You can put me as would be the example of that svg tag, which I do not know. Thank you

Comment: Sorry! your comment is unclear

Comment: About my code you can put me the example modification

Comment: make sure your `height , width` values are consistent. may be your Parent Div is smaller than the `svg`.

Comment: This is the logo image https://www.imprentaonline24.es/img/imprentaonline24.svg [1] And after trying that code that is up does not work for me. This is how it appears if I use my original code with the image in responsive. Without fixed width [enter image description here][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S9cA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It works fine from if use use directly from url. **I'm using FireFox and it works**

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <a href="index">
      <svg>
   <img src="https://www.imprentaonline24.es/img/imprentaonline24.svg"/>
</svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any specific usecase for using `img` element? Is your SVG Complex?

Comment: This is the logo image
https://www.imprentaonline24.es/img/imprentaonline24.svg [1]

And after trying that code that is up does not work for me.

This is how it appears if I use my original code with the image in responsive. Without fixed width
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S9cA.jpg

Comment: Updated Snippet, Run this snippet in FireFox. If `svg` appears below than there's something wrong with your code, update the question with the svg file and it's css classes. I'll guide you further